# javascript IE bug

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have [this](http://www.turie.eu/IEproblem) web page where are two links at the bottom (aaa, bbb) which runs bumpbox(lightbox alternative). In Opera, FF, Chrome works javascript code which connect (binocular) icon on the map with these links, but not in IE. There are no problems in the console. I've tried IE7,8. Thank you for your help!

the funcion (I think the problem is with the /* for IE */ part):

```
function fireEvent(element, event){
if (document.createEventObject){
/* for IE */
return element.fireEvent('on' + event, document.createEventObject());
}else{
/* for other browsers */
var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evt.initEvent(event, true, true);
}
return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}


google.maps.event.addListener(pano01, 'click', function() {    
fireEvent(document.getElementById("c01").getElementsByTagName("a")[0], 'click');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
return element.fireEvent('on' + event, document.createEventObject());
```

to

```
return element[event]();
```

It should work fine with click.